# pytorch hook function is not executed

Tags: python, pytorch, hook

May I know why the [pytorch hook function](https://gist.github.com/promach/b6f526c56e20f029d68e6f9041c3f5c0#file-gdas-py-L316) does not work ?

[image: code]

Comment: Can you provide the full error *backtrace* **in text**?

Comment: there is no error backtrace because the hook function is not executed.  I mean there is no error message about this.  If the hook function is executed, then the `print('grad_output')` at line 295 inside the hook function will be executed, but it is not in this case.

Comment: Ok, could you provide the relevant code from your file so we can have a closer look?

Comment: @Ivan https://gist.github.com/promach/b6f526c56e20f029d68e6f9041c3f5c0#file-gdas-py-L316

Comment: Did you make sure the hooks were properly registering on the modules. For instance by printing `print(name)` under your `for name, module in modules:` loop?

Comment: @Ivan I only have [1 instance](https://i.imgur.com/7XQgbBE.png) of `name = cells`  which is a bit strange to me

Comment: You have a single child (the `ModuleList`) which contains multiple sub-modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`torch.nn.Module.named_modules`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_modules) instead of [`torch.nn.Module.named_children`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_children). The latter will only return immediate child modules. In your case `graph`'s immediate child is `cells`, so you won't be looping over modules inside of `cells`, *i.e.* the layers defined inside the `ModuleList`.

Either use `named_modules`:

```
for name, module in graph.named_modules()
    pass
```

Or use `named_children` on `graph.cells` directly:

```
for name, module in graph.cells.named_children():
    pass
```

However, the latter alternative won't scale if you ever decide to add additional child modules to `Graph`.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `pass` inside the for-loop ?

Comment: This is just a placeholder to exit the loop, replace `pass` with the relevant code, *i.e.* `module.register_full_backward_hook(hook_fn_backward)`

Comment: Just a side question, any idea about how to interpret [the output of the hook function](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C3khPYZYp9/) ?

Comment: There's not much to 'interpret', basically for each module you output the gradient that is incoming and the gradient that is coming out. If you look at a particular module that gets `x` as input and outputs `y`. Then you have `dL/dx = dL/dy*dy/dx` using the chain rule: `dL/dy` is the incoming gradient (namely `grad_input`), and `dL/dx` is the outputted gradient (namely `grad_output`).